# How to use global stylesheet with css loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, css-loader

I try to figure out how to import/require global css which includes styles for tags like body and so.
I use css-loader + style-loader with extract text plugin.. I noticed the :global selector but didn't know where exactly I should put the global.css and import it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an assets directory with a directory for stylesheets, where you can put the global.css file. Then, in your index.js file (where you render the dom) you can

```
require('./assets/stylesheets/global.css');
```

If your loaders are set up right, and this will bring in your css file and use it to format your application.